# Azure contributions to github profile

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-repos

I work for a company that uses Azure Devops and therefore all my contributions are not stored in a github account. Is there any way to transfer them there (obviously without cloning the repository to github)

I tried to find a way to track contributions but they all require direct integration with github, which I can't do.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you define what a "contribution" is? Because Git doesn't track "contributions", it tracks "commits". If you want commits in GitHub, you need to push the repo to GitHub. Please clearly define what your objective is.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want clone contributions from Azure DevOps Repo to local then to GitHub.
you could directly use git import by going to GitHub right upper corner, click the '+' button, put your old repository’s clone URL got from ADO repos then it should be done. You needn't clone the repo to your local.

[image]

[image]

Then if you want, you could delete the repos/contributions in Azure DevOps.

If the contributions are on GitHub repos, then you needn't track them with integrations. But if they are still in different platforms, then you need to use integration to track them.